# Does $f_n(x)=(\frac{2-x}{3})^n $ converge uniformly on $[-1,4]$?

Tags: uniform-convergence

Does $f_n(x)=(\frac{2-x}{3})^n $ converge uniformly on $[-1,4]$?

I know that
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\text{undefined}  & x=-1  \\
0 & x \in (-1,4]
\end{cases}$$
and since $f(x)$ is discontinuous on$[-1,4 ]$, $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on $[-1,4]$. Is it the correct answer?

Comment: We say functions converge **to** values **on** intervals. I've edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Your pointwise limit should be,

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \;\;\;\;x = -1\\
0 & -1<x\leq 4
\end{cases} $$

But yes your argument holds otherwise.